# Does calling forward() on a model in pytorch require extra gpu memory after already having loaded the model and data in gpu memory?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I can load the model and a data sample in gpu memory, but when I call forward on the model with the sample, it gives a `CUDA out of memory` error.

I'm sure the model and data have been loaded, as my code is structured as follows (pseudocode):

```
model = Model()
sample = load_sample()
sleep(5) # to check memory usage with nvidia-smi
print('before forward')
model(sample)
print('after forward')
```

"before forward" gets printed, but "after forward" does not.

I assumed all the necessary memory for a forward pass gets allocated during construction of the model, but I don't know how else this error can happen. I also cannot find it on Google.

Python:  3.6.9
PyTorch: 1.2.0

Comment: Yes because forward will compute and store the activations on gpu

Comment: I get that, but I assumed it would be possible for pytorch to pre-allocate memory, as it is known beforehand how many parameters need gradients stored. Is that not the case?

Comment: no that is not the case as batch size etc are not known before runtime

Comment: Ah yes that's right, I forgot about the unknown batch size. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to determine the amount of space required to store the activations before runtime and hence GPU memory increases. Pytorch maintains a dynamic computation graph and hence the order of computations is not at all known before runtime. When you declare/initialize the model, only `__init__` is called and model parameters are initialized. To figure out the graph one would need to look at the `forward` call and maybe also `loss` function (if it is not within `forward` call).

Let's say we can look at the forward call before running the model but still the batch size is unknown and hence memory can't be pre-allocated for activations.

Even if the batch size is known, there could be other unknowns like sequence size (for RNN), or episode size in RL that make it hard to pre-allocate memory for activations. Even if we account for all this at the declaration, `pytorch` naturally allows for for-loops which makes it almost impossible to pre-allocate space for activations and hence GPU memory can increase during runtime depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

As Umang Gupta pointed out in the comments, GPU memory will increase during a `forward()` call on a Pytorch model, as (possibly amongst others) the batch size is not known before runtime. Therefore the required memory cannot be reserved beforehand, and the GPU memory can increase after having loaded the model and data already.